Issue with adding a scroll bar to QWidget and preventing graphics from resizing
I'm have difficulty with adding a scrollable view in my QWidget. Every time I try and add one, It doesn't seem to work and my plots which I'm displaying always end up shrinking. Here is the code which I'm using to add the scroll bar to the view.
class PlottingPage(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None, data=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.parent = parent
        self.data = data

        self.scrolls = QtWidgets.QScrollArea()
        self.scrolls.setWidgetResizable(True)

        self.widget = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.vbox = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.widget)
        self.scrolls.setWidget(self.widget)

        self.title = QtWidgets.QLabel("Plots", alignment=QtCore.Qt.AlignTop)
        self.vbox.addWidget(self.title)

        main_layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)
        main_layout.addWidget(self.scrolls)

        if self.data:
            self.IRC_File = data[0]
            self.Param_File = data[1]


    def init_plot(self):
        for energy, label in zip(self.IRC_File[0, :].reshape(1, -1), self.Param_File[0, 1]):
            for i, (param, lab) in enumerate(zip(self.IRC_File[1:, :], self.Param_File[1:,0])):
                canvas = MplCanvas(self, width=5, height=5, dpi=300, x=param, y=energy, x_label=lab, y_label=label)
                #canvas.setSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding)
                self.vbox.addWidget(canvas)

    def update_data(self, data):
        self.IRC_File = data[0]
        self.Param_File = data[1]
        print(data[0][0, :].reshape(1, -1))
        self.init_plot()

This is the outcome of the code:

Any help is greatly appreciated.
Thank you

Matplotlib's canvases don't have a proper size hint, so you have to explicitly set a minimum height for them.
